# Webmatrix - formatting MSSQL database query

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I am trying to format the output of a query in a WebMatrix 2 CSHTML file. This is the code I am using:

```
@foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
{
   @row.Firstname; + " " + @row.lastname; + " " + @row.Entry;
}
```

I am getting this error:

> "CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that the semicolons could be confusing to Razor, and they are only confusing matters.  So change the line in the brackets to

```
<text>@row.Firstname @row.lastname @row.Entry</text>
```

And see if that works.  The < text > tags tells Razor to output this directly as HTML and not use it as code.  You don't need the + " " because once you're putting out HTML, the spaces come automatically.